# Is frame of reference a point of view?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, definition, observers, relative-motion

The definition of frame of reference I found is :"It is just a coordinate". But in solving problem, my teacher always uses frame of reference by considering it at rest (although it is moving) and in so many problem solution, i found that frame of reference is used like a POV. So, I think that frame of reference is just a point of view where a coordinate is at rest. But I can't find any documentation that confirms this. I really want people to confirm the correctness of this.

Comment: The eponymous wikipedia article may be useful as a formal definition to extend the below informal descriptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between reference frame and coordinate system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/687659/)

Comment: a ref frame is where the coordinate [0,0,0] is located. if it moves, the [0,0,0] stays with this object.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "point of view" gives a better feel for what *frame of reference*  means than does "a set of co-ordinates". In a particular frame of reference certain things are considered to have particular velocities; maybe some are rest. For example, in a straight wire's frame of reference, atomic nuclei are considered stationary (neglecting thermal motion) whereas, if there is a current in the wire, free electrons are moving in it. On the other hand, in the free electrons' frame, the free electrons are stationary and the nuclei are moving.

A particular frame of reference can be given an infinite number of different co-ordinate systems. As a trivial example, our current carrying wire could be given a co-ordinate system in which the z-axis points along the wire or one in which the x-axis points along the wire. The other two orthogonal axes could point in all sorts of directions. Or we could use cylindrical polar co-ordinates...

Answer (score -1):

A frame of reference is a set of axes that is used to describe the position, orientation, and movement of objects in space. It is a coordinate system that is used to measure the position and orientation of objects in space. In physics, the frame of reference is typically chosen to be at rest, meaning that it is not moving relative to the objects being measured. This allows us to make meaningful measurements of the objects' positions and movements. So, your understanding of a frame of reference as a "point of view where a coordinate is at rest" is correct.