# Using Lorentz Transformations in Black Hole

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes

Can we use Lorentz Transformations to understand the space-time curvature around a black hole? To my understanding, the Lorentz Transformations enable us to understand time dilation, as in the case of the Twins Paradox. So can we apply these same equations to black holes? If not, why?

Comment: No. The Lorentz Transformations have nothing to say about spacetime curvature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Lorentz transformation is something that applies to a flat spacetime. A black hole spacetime isn't a flat spacetime. This is basically because there are no global frames of reference in GR: [How do frames of reference work in general relativity, and are they described by coordinate systems?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458854/how-do-frames-of-reference-work-in-general-relativity-and-are-they-described-by)

If you want to predict things like gravitational effects on time, the tool you want is the metric.

Comment: But we can still measure the time delay using the transformations falling into the black hole within line of sight, using a light signal?

Comment: If so what would that tell us about the slice of geometry it is going through?